# Local host on google refuses to connect

Tags: html, compiler-errors

So I am trying to run some basic HTML code trying to practise some forms and when I press F5 to run the code in the browser , the browser open up and I get the following error:
**This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.**

I have been getting a corrupt installation error since a few days so I tried reinstalling VS code application again to run a clean installation again but I still get the error , I tried following the instructions given by people on others questions but to no avail. As of now I can only run the html page with the help of an extension : Live server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're encountering issues with your local development environment. Here are some steps you can try to troubleshoot the problem:

1. *Check the Port:*

   - Ensure that you're using the correct port in your URL. For example, if your server is running on port 3000, the URL should be `http://localhost:3000`.
2. *Check Running Processes:*

   - Verify that your development server is actually running. If you're using Live Server or another extension, make sure it's running and serving your HTML file.
3. *Browser Cache:*

   - Clear your browser cache or try accessing the page in an incognito/private window to rule out any caching issues.
4. *Check for Other Processes on the Same Port:*

   - Another application or process might be using the same port. Try changing the port in your server configuration.
5. *Review Console for Errors:*

   - Open your browser's developer tools (usually with `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I`) and check the console for any error messages that might provide more information.

If none of these solutions work, please provide more details about your development setup, including the specific steps you take to run your HTML code and any error messages you see.